# List validation on sharepoint 2010 list

Tags: 2010, custom-list, validation, date-time

I tried to add validation on sharepoint 2010 list to validate 4 columns but, the length of this validation is greater than length of text box to write the formula. Is there any way to expand this text box or what i can do even i need all cases in this validation???

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript and the PreSave method to validate all columns and prevent saving if validation fails. This would overcome challenge of text box length in column validation.

As far as extending validation text box length for formula, I know of no way.

Answer (score 0):

If the validation is column specific then you can add validation to each column separately.  You only need to do it at the list level when the validation is related to more than one column.